# append each value from a for loop into a column cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have split a dataframe into two based on a condition. I converted the column 'ItemName' from both dataframes into a list.

I tried to use difflib to perform approximate string matching between two columns, one in each of these dataframes, both called 'ItemName'. I would like to join the list called 'matchlist' as a column into the source dataframe or on the other hand it is fine if I can append each output of the for loop into a new column in the source dataframe.

```
source = list(datadf['ItemName'])
destination = list(datadf['ItemName'])

matchlist = []
for i in source:
    x = difflib.get_close_matches(i, destination, 3, 0.6)
    matchlist.append(x)
```

I did try join and merge options in pandas but without any error the newly added columns only shown NaN values. Both the columns called 'ItemName' contain string values only.

can someone help with an idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you provide some input data from your dataframes and the desired output?

Comment: Do you think `datadf['new'] = matchlist` ?

Comment: matchlist means get a list with the inner values between the two lists? That is: 
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'] listB = ['b']  machlist = ['b]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need assign list back:

```
datadf['new'] = matchlist
```

Or use list comprehension instead loop solution:

```
datadf = pd.DataFrame({
    'ItemName': ['as','asds','as','aa','ssb','ab','sb']
})
print (datadf)
  ItemName
0       as
1     asds
2       as
3       aa
4      ssb
5       ab
6       sb

#convert to list is not necessary
L = datadf['ItemName']
datadf['new'] = [difflib.get_close_matches(i, L, 3, 0.6) for i in L]
print (datadf)
  ItemName             new
0       as  [as, as, asds]
1     asds  [asds, as, as]
2       as  [as, as, asds]
3       aa            [aa]
4      ssb       [ssb, sb]
5       ab            [ab]
6       sb       [sb, ssb]
```

EDIT:

If need check between 2 columns of different DataFrames:

```
datadf = pd.DataFrame({ 'Fruits':pd.Categorical(['apple','orange', 'apple', 'pineapple']), 
                      'Juices':pd.Categorical(['apple','orange smash','apple1','milkshake']), 
                      'Year': pd.Categorical([2011, 2011, 2012, 2012])}) 
print (datadf)
      Fruits        Juices  Year
0      apple         apple  2011
1     orange  orange smash  2011
2      apple        apple1  2012
3  pineapple     milkshake  2012

data_df_splitone = datadf[(datadf['Year'] == 2011)].copy()
data_df_splittwo = datadf[(datadf['Year'] == 2012)].copy()

L1 = data_df_splitone['Juices']
L2 = data_df_splittwo['Juices']

data_df_splitone['new'] = [difflib.get_close_matches(i, L2, 3, 0.6) for i in L1]
print (data_df_splitone)
   Fruits        Juices  Year       new
0   apple         apple  2011  [apple1]
1  orange  orange smash  2011        []
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a cool solution. As I mentioned the actual dataframe is split into two based on a condition. I made a tiny mistake in my code above. Both dataframes are not datadf, one of them is called datadf_split, which means this is split piece from the original data frame. So in that case, in the for-loop where will I tell that it need to compare values in 'ItemName' from datadf to datadf_split.?

Comment: I get the error. ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @Sudhi - Can you change `datadf = pd.DataFrame({
    'ItemName': ['as','asds','as','aa','ssb','ab','sb']
})` for sample data, I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Ok. Lets say the orginal dataframe is like this: >>>     datadf = pd.DataFrame({ 'Fruits': pd.Categorical(['apple','orange', 'mango', 'pineapple']), 'Juices': pd.Categorical(['apple shaker', 'orange smash', 'mango slice', 'pineapple milkshake']), 'Year': pd.Categorical(['2011', '2011', '2012', '2012'])})

Comment: Then I split the data, like:                                                                                
>>> data_df_splitone = datadf[(datadf['Year'] == 2011)]
>>> data_df_splittwo = datadf[(datadf['Year'] == 2012)]

Comment: Now if i try to compare the 'ItemName' between the two dataframes, how would it be. I have a dataframe with close to a million values like this.

Comment: @Sudhi - What is expected output?

Comment: Well, in this example: apple and apple shaker should be more or less closer. So the difflib should be able to add the apple shaker into a new column on datadf_splitone telling me that I have found a sort of similar item in the datadf_splittwo dataframe.

Comment: @Sudhi - ya, but in `data_df_splittwo` is no `apple`

Comment: Sorry, when I split in the case of this example it is not there. But let say in a very large dataset it is there(the one that I have). But when I split the dataset based on a condition, it doesn't break into two halves equally in size. One dataset has 12000 rows and the other has a little more than that. So when I apply your logic it seems to give me ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. So I wasn't sure if there was a way to fix it.

Comment: @Sudhi - Not 100% suure if understand, check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. As I mentioned earlier, your solution works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot. The only issue is when we have different row count in the split dataframes, it gives a value error. But nevertheless. Thanks a lot for the help. _/\_

Comment: I'd like to inform you that after I applied editted answer I dont get the value error anymore. Thanks for the help! :)